# How to separate the JSON "Allocation" Key values only to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, json, api

```
"data": {
        "status": "success",
        "message": [
            {
                "ptdb2": {
                    "Availability": {
                        "date": "2021-05-18",
                        "time": "00:00:04",
                        "car": "2",
                        "state": "Available"
                    }
                },
                "timestamp": "2021-05-18 03:57:52"
            },
            {
                "ptdb2": {
                    "Allocation": {
                        "date": "2021-05-13",
                        "time": "09:11:03",
                        "start": "1",
                        "dest": "5",
                        "ID": "16",
                        "individualID": "0",
                        "firstname": "Jack",
                        "dept": "dep",
                        "personalNo": "jack_001"
                    }
                },
                "timestamp": "2021-05-13 09:11:04"
            },
            {
                "ptdb2": {
                    "TimingsList": {
                        "null": "null"
                    }
                },
                "timestamp": "2021-05-18 03:57:52"
            }
            ]
    }
```

Please check image Allocation DATA only need to insert to DB.

Comment: Why? What do you expect to happen? What have you tried? Don't post text in an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: C# or SQL? what language do you want the solution in? Both have support for parsing and querying JSON objects